# Reparenting a process

Tags: kernel, process, module, ioctl

I create a Linux Kernel Module and I try to find a way to **re-parent a given process** or **change a given process PID**. Is there any way of doing that?

I found the following link but I could not make it work.

https://www.smartspate.com/can-change-pid-process-linux-using-kernel-module/

Comment: What is your purpose for doing either of these things?

Comment: Kindly see the answer in the next comment. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Standard unix only supports orphaning processes, not reparenting.
The result of orphaning is that the process's parent becomes pid 1.

Changing the PID of a process is also not supported in standard unix and likely has severe security implications, so it is unlikely it will ever be supported.

However, you could fork a process and then have the parent fork exit.  The result will be a new process with a new pid and ppid=1

Of course, it is always possible to modify the kernel source and install a new kernel, but if you aren't an expert in kernel code, expecting it to work is far fetched.

Comment: I tried that solution. The process did not took as a father the PID 1 but the /usr/lib/systemd/systemd --user. Which can be killed (if you kill that father process it just lock you out of the system). My final purpose is to hide a process (by changing a PID) and his new father be unkillable (like PID 1). Do you have any idea about that? Anything that can work for my purpose.

Comment: What you are trying to do is not possible specifically to prevent things from being hidden.  systemd has taken over the function of pid 1.

Comment: So it was possible in a previous kernel and now this functionality is gone? Because in the article I add it in my original question he was able to do it via kallsyms, there is no any similar way nowadays?

Comment: No, it has never been possible.  The article you found is doing something experimental that will never be adopted and is likely to be actively blocked.